# Ver si existe una imagen y colocarla en una noticia

Tags: php, html, css3, semantic-ui

Estoy haciendo una muy simple "carga de noticias" y cuando hablo de simple, créanme es muy simple... tengo una tabla donde cargo los títulos, y una pequeñita imagen a la izquierda y un resumen. Tiene mas a la derecha un botón donde el usuario entra a leer la noticia completa... 
El modelo es mas o menos asi:

[image: Estructura de la tabla]

Ahora bien, las fotos que voy a cargar estan en una carpeta que cuya ruta es "../../images/noticias" y las imagenes estan numeradas por el id de la noticia. Simple hasta ahi. Ahora bien, cuando cargo esa tabla de las noticias, busco en el directorio de las imagenes si esta la foto que corresponde a esa notcia. 
Hago lo siguiente:

```
<?php
        $nombre_fichero = "../../images/noticias/".$row['id'].".jpg";
        if (file_exists($nombre_fichero)) {
          $archivo = $row['id']."jpg";
        } else {
          $archivo = "imagen.png";
        }
      ?>

      <td><img class="ui tiny image" src="../../images/noticias/" <?php $archivo; ?>"</td>
```

La idea es que si no encuentra la foto que corresponde, "cargaría" una imagen standard del tipo:

[image: imagen si no esta la imagen que va]

ahora bien... creo que no estaría funcionando lo que estoy haciendo porque no lo carga... pues creo que le estoy pasando una cadena de texto y no un "archivo"... puede ser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que te falta hacer el echo en php e incluirlo dentro del parámetro src:

```
<img class="ui tiny image" src="../../images/noticias/<?php echo $archivo; ?>" />
```

Puedes también mejorar un poco tu código anterior de php:

```
<?php
    $archivo = 'imagen.png';

    $nombre_fichero = "../../images/noticias/$row['id'].jpg";
    if (file_exists($nombre_fichero)) {
      $archivo = "$row['id'].jpg";
    }
?>
```

O puedes utilizar el operador ternario:

```
<?php
    $nombre_fichero = "../../images/noticias/$row['id'].jpg";

    $archivo = file_exists($nombre_fichero) ? "$row['id'].jpg" : 'imagen.png';
?>
```

Comment: No te puedo creer !!! Después de almorzar pruebo

Comment: $archivo = file_exists($nombre_fichero) ? "../../images/noticias/".$row['id'].".jpg" : "../../images/noticias/imagen.png"; vi que funciona mejor poniendole la ruta entera...

Comment: Podrìas hacer entonces algo así: `$archivo = '../../images/noticias/' . file_exists($nombre_fichero) ? "$row['id'].jpg" : 'imagen.png';` esto para no repetir código.

Comment: sabes que pasa algo raro... probe cambiar la imagen 1.jpg por otra y me sigue levantando la 1.jpg inicial... es como que queda en el buffer... puede ser ?

Comment: Sí, es muy probable que esté en el caché del navegador. Puedes agregarle un cache buster para poder probar. algo como `1.jpg?v=<?php date('YmdHis') ?>`

Comment: eso en la cadena anterior ? cuando "arma" la ruta de la imagen ?

Comment: Exacto, pero idealmente solo para probar, en producción no es tan recomendado hacerlo, pues hace un request cada vez.

Comment: ah ok... si... anduvo... perfecto...